# Using ICollection with MVC & Entity framework

Tags: c#

Hi I'm learning to use MVc using Code first method. I'm having trouble understanding the use of ICollection<> with my setup. I have two classes/entitys:  'Restaurant' & 'RestaurantReview' as below:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

and.....

```
public class RestaurantReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }


}
```

now whats confusing me is the last property of the Restaurant class. Why is it of type 'ICollection' and uses my RestaurantReview class as a parameter, what does it do, hope I
have made myself clear

Answer (score 0):

It's a definition of one to many relationship.

With that property (sometimes called *Navigation Property*) Entity Framework will be able to connect `Review` with `Restaurant` it was written about. It will also allow you to get `Review` entities for given `Restaurant` entity really easily.

You can also remove `public int RestaurantId { get; set; }` from `RestaurantReview` class - That column is gonna be generated automatically by EF because of `ICollection<RestaurantReview>` in `Restaurant` class.